# Default Liferay Web Content View Permissions

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, web-content

we have a portal (6.2 CE GA3) where people are creating Web Contents.

When a new Web Content is created, it´s visibility is automatically set to "Site-Members". This requires the editors to change this for each individual Web Content:

[image]

Is there any way to set this to "Guest Role" as the new standard ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you happen to have *only* private pages, or are you creating the web content from a private page? This might lead to the default being chosen this way.

I am positively aware of some defaults for the Document Library. It might be that there's a default for Web Content as well that says: If you're coming from the Control Panel *and* you have private pages, Liferay is better safe than sorry and defaults to *site member visibility*. If you *only* have public pages, Liferay will default to public web content in any case.

As you state in the comment below, I'm confident that this is the case. The conditions for the defaults:

- If content is added from a public page: Default is *public*
- If content is added from a private page: Default is *member only*
- If content is added from Control Panel / Site Administration *and* you have any private pages in this site: Default to *member only* ("better safe than sorry")
- If content is added from Control Panel / Site Administration *and* no private pages exist in this site: Default to *public*

Follow Tobias' suggestion in the comments and upgrade if you need to get rid of the private page.

Comment: Hi Olaf - we have plenty of public pages (only one private) and I am not coming from a private page. I log in, go to the control panel and work on my Web Contents. Any other way to set "Guest Role" as standard ?

Comment: Hi Olaf - I checked the code: LIferay only sets the "Guest Role" permission if there is no private layout at all. Since we have one private layout (that I can´t delete because liferay tells me I need at least one private layout ) it seems we´re stuck with the "Site-Member" pre selection ...

Comment: @Breiti: Since 6.2 CE GA4 it should be possible to delete the private pages, see [LPS-45170](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-45170).

Comment: Thanks a lot you two - that´s the solution: 1) Upgrade 2) get rid of private layouts or 1-b) write hook